# Accessing pre-filled input fields in controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the best way to access pre-filled input fields values in angularjs? For example, how can I access the value of variable1 (which is pre-filled on pageload) within controller scope? I am using ng-model directive on the hidden input field and using $scope.formData.variable1 to access in the controller but with no luck. I tried searching in the web for similar issue, but most of the examples were related to accessing form field on submit or click. [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/r7WbSKYhpqvl0jRHIeeY?p=preview) is link to plnkr

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">
<h1>{{message}}</h1>
<form name="formData">

  <input type="hidden" name="variable1" ng-model="formdata.variable1" value="abc" />
</form>
```

AngularJs Code:

```
(function() {

  var app = angular.module("testapp", []);

  var MainController = function($scope) {
    console.log($scope.formData.variable1);

    $scope.message = "Hello, Angular!";


  };

  app.controller("MainController", ["$scope", MainController]);

}());
```

Comment: It won't be pre-filled if `$scope.formData.variable1` doesn't have a value when controller initializes, or after an ajax request provides it a value. Also can't use `ng-model` on hidden input

Comment: why don't you simply do `$scope.formData.variable1 = 'abd';` in beginning of `MainController` controller

Comment: What alternative can I use since all those hidden variables would be needed to pass to an ajax call? Can we do anything like $(form).serialize that exists in jquery?

Comment: @jad-panda: In this code sample, I am hardcoding it, but in my actual code, those input variables are set using the server side code. For example <cfif isdefined("Form.variable1"><input type="hidden" name="variable1" ng-model="formdata.variable1" value="#Form.variable1#" /></cfif>

Comment: @fn79 then you use service. `$http` promises and the populate the field.

Comment: If you are doing a lot of server side templating, AngularJS may not be the best framework to use for the front end.  If you really need to, what you can do is create a directive instead `<default-input value="abc">` that just has a template and bind that value via the controller/link to the model.  It's a roundabout way of doing it.  Using `ng-init` is also a possibility, but that's also an ugly solution.

Comment: If you have to change all the forms to fit angular, might as well just set up data api that angular can get the data from

Comment: OK, may be my question is not clear. I just need to access the input field value, similar to document.getElementById("variable1").value or $("#variable1").val(). Are you saying that this is not possible using angularjs?

Comment: @fn79 typically there wouldn't be a need for hidden input in angular, because in angular the data is in the model, and the view only gets created based on model and there is no need to pass hidden fields to view

Comment: @fn79 yes it is certainly possible to get the value using DOM querying. There's nothing preventing you from doing that, it's just that Angular is designed for data binding and what you are doing is antithetical to Angular.  You may run into more problems down the line if you keep trying to do things without using the data bindings.

Comment: You can actually use document.getElementById("variable1").value removing the ng-model directive to avoid messing with the value set on the server but you won't be able to do two-way binding after that. What do you need those values for?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. using ng-init;

```
<input name="data[name]"
       ng-model="data.name" 
       ng-init="data.name='mark'" />
```

or

You can use directive. something like this.

```
app
.directive('ngDefaultValue', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $parse) {
        $parse($attrs.ngModel).assign($scope, $attrs.ngDefaultValue || $attrs.value);
    }
  };
});
```